# Regex positive look behind notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use regex to grab the last 3 digits of a string that varies in size. The beginning of the string always leads with name-
Examples:

"Name-0000425"
"Name-00123"
"Name-123"

I want the regex to grab the last 3 digits of this number and replace it with these digits.  This is the regex I have tried but it only grabs the first 3 digits.

```
(?-s)(?<=Name-)(\d{3})
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `hot-` when you want `name-`? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
(?<=Name-)\d*(\d{3})
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZdW5Xc/1).

Alternatively, you may also use `(Name-)\d*(\d{3})` and replace with `$1$2`.

**Details**

- `(?<=Name-)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `Name-`
- `\d*` - any zero or more digits
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern): three digits.

**NOTES**

- If you only want to remove initial zeros, you can use the `(?<=Name-)0+(\d{3})` regex.
- If there can be anything else before the last three digits on the line, you may use `(?<=Name-).*(\d{3})`.
- If there can be anything else before the last three digits that are inside double quotes on a single line, you may use `(?<=Name-)[^"\n\r]*(\d{3})`.

Comment: Awesome I was missing the \d*  thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Shortest regex will be...

Find what: `\d{3}"`
Replace it with `789"`